# internet share pc to android

Tags: settings, reverse-tether

I'm using Android 4.4.2 (samsung galaxy s duos 3 ). I've a PC at home which has highspeed broadband internet connection. I don't have wireless router or access point. I just want to use PC's internet connection on my phone. I've tried multiple methods but none seems to work.

Comment: This is called [tag:reverse-tether]ing. You might want to browse with this keyword first. Also, you have to mention what "multiple methods" you have done, so we would know and not suggesting the same methods.

Comment: If your pc has a wireless adapter you could use that to create a temporary wireless network to connect with your phone